# Let $U=\{p \in \mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{R}):p''(6)=0\}$. Find a basis of $U$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

Let $U=\{p \in \mathcal{P}_4(\mathbb{R}):p''(6)=0\}$. Find a basis of $U$. I just have a question about how to show that the list that I found is a basis.

Here is what I found:

Let $p \in U$, then $p(x)=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4$ with $a,b,c,d,e \in \mathbb{R}$. We determine now $a,b,c,d,e$ using second derivative of $p$ at $6$.

We have that $p''(6)=2c+36d+432e=0 \iff c=-18d-216e$. Thus, each polynomial $p$ of $U$ is of the form: $p(x)=a+bx+d(x^3-18x^2)+e(x^4-216x^2)$. So, the list $(1,x,x^3-18x^2,x^4-216x^2)$ might be a basis of $U$. $(1,x,x^3-18x^2,x^4-216x^2)$ is clearly linearly independent, since they all have different degrees.

But, I don't really see how to show that each $p \in U$ is linear combination of $(1,x,x^3-18x^2,x^4-216x^2)$. Does it follow directly after I found $a,b,c,d,e$ using second derivative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is fine: Form $p(x)=a+bx+d(x^3-18x^2)+e(x^4-216x^2)$ you can deduce that ever polynomial in $U$ is a linear combination of your basis; and the linar independence follows form the degree argument.

Another approach is to identificate every polynomial of degree less or equal than 4, with a vector in $\Bbb R^5$ though its coefficientes:
$$a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4+fx^5\in{\cal P}_4(\Bbb R) \longleftrightarrow (a,b,c,d,e,f)\in\Bbb R^5.$$
So you can take your basis of $U$, convert into $\Bbb R^5$ vectors and try to show that the range of the matrix formed by these vectors has range 4.